# Flask to NextJS - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: python, flask, frontend, cors, backend

I created an api call from my backend (Flask app that is already deployed) to my frontend (NextJS) but this error occurs:

localhost/:1 Access to fetch at 'https://my-backend-link.onrender.com/api/prediction' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

I tried calling it in both my local and deployed frontend but the error occurs for both instances. Here is how my backend looks like:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r"/api/prediction": {"origins": ["http://localhost:3000", "https://my-frontend-link.onrender.com"]}})

@app.route('/')
def show_docs():
    return render_template('documentation.html')

@app.route('/api/prediction', methods=['POST'])  
def get_prediction():
    ingredients = request.json.get('ingredients')
    if not ingredients:
        return jsonify({"error": "Ingredients not provided!"}), 400

    print(ingredients)
    prediction = predict(ingredients)
    return jsonify({"prediction": prediction})

def predict(ingredients):
    -----

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=8080)
```

and this is how i call the api in my frontend:

```
const url = 'https://my-backend-link.onrender.com/api';

export const getPrediction = async (nerList: string) => {
  try {
    console.log('Getting Prediction!!');
    const response = await fetch(`${url}/prediction`, {
      method: 'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ ingredients: nerList }),
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const result = await response.json();
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    } else {
      console.error('Failed to fetch data');
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

Note: The app works fine when I run and call the backend locally.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Your code looks fine, areas you can debug in further: 1) Is the deployed backend running the code you are looking at or is it running some old code? 2) Is it possible that there may be intermediate processes in between the client and the server which may be modifying the response headers?

Comment: You need to modify your CORS configuration: allow request header `Content-Type`.